# How to find the obj file or library that contains specific function body?

Tags: gcc, ld

A binary consisted of lots of obj file and libraries,

Use *objdump*  I can get a list all symbols in this binary.

For example:

```
000342c4 l     F .text  000000cc xdrmem_getlong

00034390 l     F .text  000000cc xdrmem_putlong

0003445c l     F .text  0000008c xdrmem_getbytes

000344e8 l     F .text  0000008c xdrmem_putbytes

00034574 l     F .text  00000038 xdrmem_getpos
```

My question is how to find the object file or pre-built library that contains specified function such as "xdrmem_putbytes" in above example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see the object file contents of a .so file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919884/how-to-see-the-object-file-contents-of-a-so-file)

Comment: "A binary consisted of lots of obj file and libraries". No, it doesn't.
See [How to see the object file contents of a .so file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48919884/1362568)